# Bad compilation command from autoconf test

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf

I'm trying to write an autoconf test for a C++ library. I followed http://nerdland.net/2009/07/detecting-c-libraries-with-autotools/ . My check looks like this:

```
SAVED_LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -lMyLib"
AC_LINK_IFELSE(
  [AC_LANG_PROGRAM([#include <mylibheader.hpp>],
    [MyLibNamespace::SomeObject obj()])],
  [TEST_LIBS="$TEST_LIBS -lMyLib"] [HAVE_MYLIB=1],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR([libMyLib is not installed.])])
LDFLAGS=$SAVED_LDFLAGS
```

The test fails. If i check config.log the problem seems to be with the generated compilation command given by autoconf for the check:

```
g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -lMyLib conftest.cpp
```

As you can see, the -l params aren't at the end, after all inputs and outpus. If i copy&paste the conftest.cpp code from config.log i can make it compile with:

```
g++ -o conftest -g -O2  conftest.cpp -lMyLib
```

How can autoconf be wrong? How may i fix this?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether `-l` parameters are supplied before or after the input file. What is the actual error?

Comment: it does... As i tell above it compiles with -lMyLib at the end, but not if it's before my inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding `-lMyLib` to `LDFLAGS` instead of adding to `LIBS`.  In other words, do this instead:

```
SAVED_LIBS=$LIBS
LIBS="-lMyLib $LIBS"
AC_LINK_IFELSE(
  [AC_LANG_PROGRAM([#include <mylibheader.hpp>],
    [MyLibNamespace::SomeObject obj()])],
  [TEST_LIBS="$TEST_LIBS -lMyLib"] [HAVE_MYLIB=1],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR([libMyLib is not installed.])])
LIBS=$SAVED_LIBS
```

**Edit:** link order of libraries is important, so I've updated the `LIBS=` line to link `MyLib` *before* the other libraries, if any, with the assumption that `MyLib` may depend on other libraries.

Comment: This makes the rest of the libraries i had in LDFLAGS before this test to be echoed after all inputs (before the change you suggest they got echoed before them). -lMyLib still gets printed before them :(

Comment: Other libraries shouldn't be in LDFLAGS either.  See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Preset-Output-Variables.html) for autoconf where it says "Don't use this variable to pass library names (-l) to the linker; use LIBS instead."

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm having problems with HAVE_MYLIB not being set in config.hpp, but at least it does pass.